# Server refused our key error

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, lubuntu

I try to connect Ubuntu 16.04 using ssh following this [tutorial](https://linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/).

In my version of putty there is only one RSA option so I used that. I generated a key beginning with `ssh-rsa`, but I always getting this error:

```
Server refused our key error
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue myself.

I misspelled the file `authorised_keys` instead of `authorized_keys` in `~/.ssh/`

Silly but true.